# AWS Glue - Log execution time of glue job to cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Is there any way to log execution time of glue job and create metric to trace it in cloudwatch? I have over 200 jobs of spark ver 2 and I had found in metrics and log but it don't log execution time. How can AWS calculated execution time in history of job

Comment: What about `glue.driver.streaming.batchProcessingTimeInMs`or `glue.driver.aggregate.elapsedTime`?

Comment: Thanks Marcin but when I check `glue.driver.streaming.batchProcessingTimeInMs` it's only for stream job, about `glue.driver.aggregate.elapsedTime` it don't show anything in cloudwatch